# What is "git checkout 0d1d7fc32 ."

Tags: git

I found this command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

**git check out oneThing anotherThing**

oneThing is commit hash

anotherThing is .

What does it do exactly?

It is unclear after reading official doc [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

Answer (score 0):

It is the option `git checkout [-p|--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>…` from the documentation. Your anotherThing (`.`) is just referencing to the current folder.

So what the command does:

> git checkout with  or --patch is used to restore modified or
>   deleted paths to their original contents from the index or replace
>   paths with the contents from a named  (most often a
>   commit-ish).